# why isn't my program compiling

Tags: c++

I keep getting an error: Function `roll` could not be resolved. I'm not sure it is because of the scope and if it is, how do I fix it?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    roll();
}

int playerSum = 0;
int dice [5];

void roll(){
  for(int i =0;i<6;i++){
      int randNum = rand()%600 + 1;
      dice[i]= randNum;
      cout<<dice[i]<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Put a forward declaration `void roll();` before main.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting roll above main, before you call it.

Alternatively, you can declare void roll(); above main and define it afterward.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler hasn't seen the roll() function definition before it sees the reference to it in main().  Move main declaration to the bottom of the file.

Answer (score 1):

A few problems.

1) Place forward declaration `void roll()` prototype before `main` to let complier know about the `roll.`

2) `int dice [5]` is to small to keep 6 elements - it will invoke Undefined Behaviour.

3) No need to use global array `dice`.

4) You may want to `seed` random generator otherwise you receive same numbers every time you run the program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

void roll();

int main() {

    roll();
    return 0;
}

void roll(){
    int dice[6];
    int randNum; 

    for(int i =0; i<6; i++){
        randNum = rand()%600 + 1;
        dice[i] = randNum;
        cout<< dice[i] <<endl;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
584                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
287                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
178                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
116                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
594                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
536
```

Answer (score 0):

*I initially assumed this question would be a duplicate.   To my surprise, I could not find a C++-tagged duplicate in a search of StackOverflow.   So I'm posting an answer instead.*

At a minimum, a C++ compiler needs to see a declaration of a function in the same compilation unit BEFORE it is first called.

This means, before the call of `roll()` in `main()`, there needs to be a declaration of `roll()`.  For example;

```
void roll();       //  declaration of roll()

int main()
{
     roll();
}

void roll()      //  definition of roll()
{
     //   your code 
}
```

This approach (a declaration that is not a definition, placed before the code that calls the function) has an advantage that the definition of `roll()` can be moved to another compilation unit (aka source file) if desired  (assuming, of course, that the build process correctly compiles all source files and links object files as required).

A definition is formally a type of declaration, so an alternative is to move `main()` to the end of the source file.

```
void roll();     // declaration of roll()

void roll()      //  definition of roll()
{
    //   your code 
}

int main()
{
     roll();
}
```

Technically, the declaration of `roll()` can be removed in this case, since a definition is a type of declaration.  One disadvantage of doing so is that, if someone subsequently decides to move the definition of `roll()` somewhere else (e.g. to another source file) then it is STILL necessary to reintroduce a declaration of `roll()` before `main()`.